# Splunk - Remove Curly Braces from Result

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have some events in a Splunk index. These events include values with curly braces. For example, here is one log:

```
[INFO]    2023-03-28 15:27:16 trace={ be7c13efa559de63b4a95eab13f14722 }, method={ GET }, statusCode={ 200 }, duration={ 277.429137ms }
```

I am trying to extract the `statusCode` and `duration`. Currently, I'm trying:

```
index=my_index

| rex field=_statusCode "\{ (?<statusCode>.*) \}"
| rex field=_duration "\{ (?<Duration>.*) \}"

| table 
  _statusCode
  _duration
```

However, I still have braces. I need to remove the braces to be able to add additional evaluations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it safe to assume the fields `statusCode` and `duration` currently hold "`{ 200 }`" and "`{ 277.429137ms }`", respectively?

Instead of using a regular expression to create a new field, use `eval .. replace` to clean up the fields you have:

```
| eval statusCode=replace(statusCode,"\D","")
| eval duration=replace(duration,"[^\.\w]","")
```

Alternatively, if you don't have those fields yet, this will extract them both for you (returning just what you're looking for with each):

```
| rex field=_raw "statusCode\D+(?<statusCode>\d+)"
| rex field=_raw "duration\W+(?<duration>[\.\w]+)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with this.

The `| rex` syntax is back to front. The `field=` argument is the target field to run the extraction against and the `(?<field>.*)` regex is the name of the extracted field.

Here is a run anywhere example to demonstrate this:

```
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="2023-03-28 15:27:16 trace={ be7c13efa559de63b4a95eab13f14722 }, method={ GET }, statusCode={ 200 }, duration={ 277.429137ms }"
| extract
| rex field=statusCode "\{ (?<extracted_statusCode>.*) \}" 
| rex field=duration "\{ (?<extracted_duration>.*) \}" 
| table extracted_statusCode, extracted_duration
```